# Getting Cannot find name 'HEROES' error in Angular tutorial

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to learn angular from https://angular.io getting started tutorial. I got stuck up at step **4. Displaying a list** where i get an error in HeroesComponent saying

> Cannot find name 'HEROES'
>   Below is my code
>   HeroesComponenet.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes = HEROES; // ==> this is where i get error.

  selectedHero: Hero;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

> mock-heroes.ts file

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

I am using Angular 6 and IDE is VS CODE

Thank in advance.
[image: File Structure]

Comment: The path to mock-heroes.ts might be wrong. If it's in the same directory then you can do `import { HEROES } from ./mock-heroes`

Comment: what is your file structure? Are those files in correct places?

Comment: @lulian the files are structured as mentioned in the tutorial still am not getting it.

Comment: @MartinCoskcucker uploaded file structure for your reference

Comment: Got it resolved. My bad i was using a colon **heroes: HEROES;** instead of **=**. Thank you guys. However why it was throwing error when it accepts **selectedHero: Hero;** but not **heroes: HEROES;** just curious

Answer (score 0):

you can't import a const with the standert import convention. Need to create an identifier to the const using `import as`

```
import * as hero from '../mock-heroes';
heroes = hero.HEROES; // use the class
```

Comment: the const import is coming straight from the official angular.io tutorial. https://stackblitz.com/angular/xongoyjllpr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts

Comment: @TimM checked the sample code from the [link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xongoyjllpr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts) it was helpful to find out what i missed.

Answer (score 0):

At first, check your folder structure.You can find live example on:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#final-code-review